# Image in storage/app/public returns 404 when trying to get it in index.blade.php

Tags: laravel

I need an image in my index blade, but I've never done this in Laravel. I keep getting 404's back, when I try.

I've tried altering the route in the asset() function multiple times. Nothing seems to work.

```
                <img src="{{ asset('public/storage/img/wvzonline_logo.png') }}" alt="Het logo van WVZ.Online">
```

I ran the line down here too.

```
php artisan storage:link
```

At the moment I get 404's not found. What I want is the image displayed, of course.

Comment: asset() refers to public folder not storage. in your case you can get like storage_path('app/public/img/wvzonline_logo.png');

Comment: Did you try accessing the image in `http://localhost/public/storage/imgwvzonline_logo.png`? By typing into the address bar

Comment: @PrinceKumarDwivedi It returns the following:    Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/Users/Scott/Desktop/School/Jaar3/Stage/PVB/B1-K2/storage/app/public/img/wvzonline_logo.png

Comment: @CloudSohJunFu Blank page with "Not available"

Comment: Maybe `http://localhost/storage/imgwvzonline_logo.png` or `http://localhost/imgwvzonline_logo.png`? Check your `config/filesystems.php` to see where your `public` disk map to

Comment: First of all please do check if `wvzonline_logo.png` exists in the folder `public/storage/img`. If yes, give this a try -> `{{ asset('/storage/img/wvzonline_logo.png') }}`

Comment: @thebrownkid It's in the folder storage/app/public/img. I just had that route from a different SO article. Your snippet works, though. If you post it as an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all please do check if `wvzonline_logo.png` exists in the folder `public/storage/img`.

If yes, give this a try -> `{{ asset('/storage/img/wvzonline_logo.png') }}`

> As the symlink is created successfully you can use the `asset()` to access the images in the storage folder.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to prefix `public` in the asset path, if you do so, you would be accessing `http://localhost/public/storage/image.png`.

Your `http://localhost` is already in the `public` folder scope, so that you only have to access the `storage` via `asset('storage/image.png')`. Or you can use `Storage::url('image.png')` to get the path. However, note that the url is affected by the `APP_URL` in your `.env`.

```
app
config
database
public -|
  index.php
  storage -|
    image.png
storage
  app
    public
      image.png
```

The `config/filesystems.php` specified the path of your storage, and the url to access it. Client are unable to view the image unless you put it in the public folder (by `php artisan storage:link`, which symlinks your `storage` folder with `public/storage`).